# Equality of vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Given $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b} = \vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}$

Does that implies $\vec{b} =\vec{c}$ if equality holds for arbitrary $\vec{a}$ ?
I think this only holds if we specify $\vec{b}$ explicitly. Otherwise solution is not unique IMO.

Comment: If it holds for all $\vec a$, take the vectors of the standard basis $(1,0,0,...) \, , \, (0,1,0,...)$ for $\vec a$ to see that all components of $\vec b$ and $\vec c$ are equal.

Comment: Except when $a$ is the zero vector, the basis argument above works.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Are you trying to say there is an exception?

Comment: The equality holds trivially for $a=0$, that's what I mean. And if $a$ isn't zero, then you use the basis argument above.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг But $\vec a$ is supposed to be arbitrary.  There's no reason to worry about the case that $\vec a = 0$, since one can simply choose it not to be zero.

Comment: That is true as well. Maybe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\vec{a}$ is the standard basis vector $e_i$ then $\vec{a}.\vec{b}=b_i$ the $i$-th component of $\vec{b}$. Similarly $\vec{a}.\vec{c}=c_i$. Hence we get the component-wise equality of $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$. So $\vec{b}=\vec{c}$.

Comment: What if $\vec{a}$ is not basis vector?

Comment: You said the equality holds for all $\vec{a}$ right? So in particular it holds for basis vectors.

Comment: But i think only $e_i$th components check. What about others?

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz Why do you need to care about others when you have already deduced $\vec b = \vec c$?

Comment: I mean we have $a_1(b_1-c_1)+a_2(b_2-c_2) = 0$. So you let $a_i=0$ lets say $a_1$. Then you can't comment about $b_1 and c_1$

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz $\vec a$ is arbitrary so you can choose it to take as many different values as you need.  One choice of $\vec a$ determines $b_1 = c_1$, then the next determines $b_2 = c_2$.

Comment: i got your point. Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it holds for the one vector $\vec a = \vec b - \vec c$, then necessarily $\vec b = \vec c$: $$0 = \vec a \cdot \vec b - \vec a \cdot \vec c = \vec a \cdot (\vec b - \vec c) = (\vec b - \vec c) \cdot (\vec b - \vec c) = \| \vec b - \vec c \|^2.$$

(This is assuming you are working with a vector space over $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: +1.I like this answer. This one puts the icing on the cake. Why need arbitrary vectors when one suffices?

Comment: Nice answer, but i will choose the first answer to accepted one. Anyway +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If $\{e_i\}_i $ is an ortonormal base then for every vector $a$ we have
 $$a=\sum a_ie_i$$ 
where $a_i=a\cdot e_i$. 
So it is sufficient that your relation holds for all the element of a ortonormal base for $b$ to be equal to $c$